# Is there any alternative way to session based user access control?

Tags: php, session, authentication

For my project I'm  using session based access control to handle different type of users, 
is it secure? is there any other way to do same thing?
This is my coding.

```
// Note : $_SESSION['role']==1 refer to Admin and ['role']==3 refer to staff 

session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['cur_user'])&&($_SESSION['role']==1) || ($_SESSION['role']==3)  )
{
   //if user login details is correct .. doing some stuff         
?>

<!-- Website Content-->

<?php
}

else{
    unset($_SESSION['cur_user']);
    session_destroy();
    header ("location:login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: session is secure than a cookie based system

Comment: u can run your sessions through mysql, this is a great alternative because you can run the session through multiple servers